# Complex signature in Typescript function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Following generic function takes a object of functions and returns an object with same propnames valued with returning value of the corresponding function.

```
const combineValues = obj => { 
      const res = {};
      for (const k in obj){
        res[k] = obj[k]()
      }
      return res;
    } 
const combined = combineValues({
  n: () => 1,
  s: () => 's'
}); // { n: 1, s: 's' }
```

Tryed to define a signature and an implementation for this function in Typescript

```
const combineValues =
  <K extends string> (obj: Record<K, () => any>): Record < K, any > => {
    const res = {} as Record<K, any>;
    for (const k in obj){
      res[k] = obj[k]()
    }
    return res;
  }

const combined = combineValues({
  n, s
}) // Record<"n" | "s", any>
```

but `combined` doesn't keep original typings for values

```
const combcombineValues = <K extends string, T>(obj: Record<K, () => T>): Record<K, T> => {
    const res = {} as Record<K, T>;
    for (const k in obj){
      res[k] = obj[k]()
    }
    return res;
  }
```

works only if all function props return same type `T`

is it possible to fully define it in Typescript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in the current version of TypeScript (v2.7) without waiting for conditional types, by using [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types), a feature of TypeScript in which functions can infer types in what seems like the "backwards" direction, from output to input.

First let's define the mapped type `Funcs<T>` which takes a plain object and turns it into an object whose properties are all functions returning the property types of the plain object:

```
type Funcs<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (...args:any[]) => T[K] }
```

Note how this type is basically backwards from what you want to do.  Now let's type `combineValues()`:

```
const combineValues = <T>(obj: Funcs<T>): T => {
    const res = {} as T;  // only change in body
    for (const k in obj) {
        res[k] = obj[k]()
    }
    return res;
}
```

which, as you can see, takes a `Funcs<T>` as input and returns a `T` as output.  Let's see if it works:

```
const combined = combineValues({
    n: () => 1,
    s: () => 's'
}); // { n: number, s: string }
```

That's *almost* what you wanted.  The only difference is that TypeScript tends to interpret `() => 1` as a function that returns a `number` and not a function that returns the literal `1`.  There are things you can do to work around that; the simplest (although a bit repetitive) is to assert the return type literals:

```
const combined = combineValues({
    n: () => 1 as 1,
    s: () => 's' as 's'
}); // { n: 1, s: 's' }
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

UPDATE:  It was noted that the compiler appears to type `combined` as `{n: any, s: any}` in TypeScript 2.7.  Fortunately, this only seems to be happening when you inspect the type with Intellisense, as (I think) noted in [Microsoft/TypeScript#14041](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14041).  If you actually use the value, you will see that it has the proper type:

```
combined.n = 0 // error, 0 is not assignable to 1
combined.s = 0 // error, 0 is not assignable to 's'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Funcs%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20%28...args%3Aany%5B%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20combineValues%20%3D%20%3CT%3E%28obj%3A%20Funcs%3CT%3E%29%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20res%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28const%20k%20in%20obj%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bk%5D%28%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20res%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20combined%20%3D%20combineValues%28%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20n%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%201%20as%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%27s%27%20as%20%27s%27%0D%0A%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20n%3A%201%2C%20s%3A%20%27s%27%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Acombined.n%20%3D%200%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%200%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%201%0D%0Acombined.s%20%3D%200%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%200%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20%27s%27%0D%0A)

So, I guess I stand by this answer, although the Intellisense bug is unfortunate.  Good luck again!

Comment: I'm trying your solution with TS v2.7.2 but compiler still yelds { n: any; s: any; } with no complaints. It works, however, with TS v2.8 (next)

Comment: Uh oh!  I’ll look into it when I get to a real computer.  If I can’t fix it I’ll remove the answer.

Comment: See update.  It works in 2.7.2 but a bug in Intellisense is making it look like it doesn't.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in typescript 2.8 using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847) (2.8 in not yet released at the time of writing, you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@next` it is planned for a [March release](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#28-march-2018)).

```
// ReturnType<T> below is from 2.8 and is a conditional type
type AllReturnTypes<T extends { [name: string]: (...args: any[]) => any }> = { [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]> }
const combineValues = <T extends { [name: string]: () => any }>(obj: T): AllReturnTypes<T> => {
    const res = {} as AllReturnTypes<T>;
    for (const k in obj) {
        res[k] = obj[k]()
    }
    return res;
}

const combined = combineValues({
    n: () => 1, s: () => ""
}) // will be of type { n: number, s: string }
```